# Using dominated convergence theorem on a diverging Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

This came up in a proof I was writing and I was surprised by how difficult this ended up being. I am trying to use a dominated convergence theorem argument on the series of functions
$$f_n(\theta )=\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^ke^{ik\theta}}{k},$$
otherwise I need to find a function $g(\theta )$ with the property $|f_n(\theta )|<g(\theta )$ and that $g$ is Lebesgue integrable over $(-\pi ,\pi )$.

I started by breaking real and imaginary components apart:
$$|f_n(\theta )|=\left\lvert\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k\cos{k\theta}}{k}\right\rvert +\left\lvert\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k\sin{k\theta}}{k}\right\rvert,$$
Now the sine summation is the well known Fourier approximation of the sawtooth wave, which seems simple enough to bound by a constant for all $n$ although I haven't seen those arguments explicitly spelled out before.

The cosine summation however seems a little more difficult to handle. The cosine series limits to $-\frac{1}{2}\left(\log( 1+\cos{\theta})+\log{2}\right)$. I've found through numerical computation that $\left\lvert\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k\cos{k\theta}}{k}\right\rvert\le \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}|\log( 1+\cos{\theta})+\log{2}|$ where the right is independent of $n$, but I can't figure out how to prove this.

Essentially I feel like I'm looking for a generic result about Gibbs overshoots being bounded by a constant, even on approximations of diverging functions. And if there's an easier observation I can make about using DCT on Fourier series that would be helpful as well.

Comment: what are you trying to prove here?

Comment: That for the $f_n(\theta )$ functions I described there exists an integrable function $g(\theta )$ with the property $|f_n(\theta )|<g(\theta )$ for all $n$.